# How to create spark dataframe with column name which contains dot/period?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have data in a list and want to convert it to a spark dataframe with one of the column names containing a "."

I wrote the below code which ran without any errors.

```
input_data = [('retail', '2017-01-03T13:21:00', 134),
                     ('retail', '2017-01-03T13:21:00', 100)]
rdd_schema = StructType([StructField('business', StringType(), True), \
                         StructField('date', StringType(), True), \
                         StructField("`US.sales`", FloatType(), True)])
input_mock_df = spark.createDataFrame(input_mock_rdd_map, rdd_schema)
```

The below code returns the column names

```
input_mock_df.columns
```

But any operations on this dataframe is giving error for example

```
input_mock_df.count()
```

How do I make a valid spark dataframe which contains a "."?

**Note**:

- I dont give "." in the column name the code works perfectly.
- I want to solve it using native spark and not use pandas etc

Comment: also tried this without success, seems like dot is reserved for traversing structs

Comment: the dot signifies (tableName.columnName) structure. I am not sure there would be a possible way out.

Comment: you don't have to use ` character for field names while defining a schema. You need that character when using the column name. Just remove that character in schema definition and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran the below code

```
input_data = [('retail', '2017-01-03T13:21:00', 134),
                 ('retail', '2017-01-03T13:21:00', 100)]
rdd_schema = StructType([StructField('business', StringType(), True), \
                     StructField('date', StringType(), True), \
                     StructField("US.sales", IntegerType(), True)])

input_mock_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(input_data, rdd_schema)

input_mock_df.count()
```

and it works fine returning the count as 2. Please try and reply