# PySpark: Cannot create small dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to create a small dataframe so that I can save two scalars (doubles) and a string

from [How to create spark dataframe with column name which contains dot/period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146857/how-to-create-spark-dataframe-with-column-name-which-contains-dot-period)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType

input_data = ([output_stem, paired_p_value, scalar_pearson])

schema = StructType([StructField("Comparison", StringType(), False), \
                     StructField("Paired p-value", DoubleType(), False), \
                     StructField("Pearson coefficient", DoubleType(), True)])
df_compare_AF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(input_data, schema)
display(df_compare_AF)
```

producing the error message:

`TypeError: StructType can not accept object 's3://sanford-biofx-dev/con/dev3/dev' in type <class 'str'>` which doesn't make any sense to me, this column was *meant* for strings

my other solution is from
[Add new rows to pyspark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685609/add-new-rows-to-pyspark-dataframe)

```
columns = ["comparison", "paired p", "Pearson coefficient"]
vals = [output_stem, paired_p_value, scalar_pearson]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
display(df)
```

but this gives an error: `TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>`

I just want a small dataframe:

```
comparison | paired p-value | Pearson Coefficient
-------------------------------------------------
s3://sadf  |   0.045        | -0.039
```

Comment: Replace `([output_stem, paired_p_value, scalar_pearson])` with `([output_stem, paired_p_value, scalar_pearson], )` or `[[output_stem, paired_p_value, scalar_pearson]]`

Comment: @10465355saysReinstateMonica that works, if you put your solution as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to put a comma of mystery at the end of `input_data` thanks to @10465355 says Reinstate Monica 
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType

```
input_data = ([output_stem, paired_p_value, scalar_pearson],)

schema = StructType([StructField("Comparison", StringType(), False), \
                     StructField("Paired p-value", DoubleType(), False), \
                     StructField("Pearson coefficient", DoubleType(), True)])
df_compare_AF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(input_data, schema)
display(df_compare_AF)
```

I don't understand *why* this comma is necessary, or what it does, but it seems to do the job

Comment: _I don't understand why this comma is necessary_ - ["Tuples may be constructed in a number of ways: ... Using a trailing comma for a singleton tuple: a, or (a,)"](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)